# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable using restframework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building a customer user using restframework, but I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

while making a `POST` request using postman.

Here is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /auth/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dailycoding/Desktop/projects/myapp/users/views.py", line 7, in post
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import(BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,username,email,password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError("users should have a username")
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError("users should have an email")
        user = self.model(username=username,email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
    def create_superuser(self,username,email,password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError("password should not be none")

        user = self.create_user(username,email,password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user 
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True,db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True,db_index=True) 

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def tokens(self):
        return ''
```

The error point here in `views.py` line 7, which this line of code:

```
serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)

from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer

class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer  # should been defined here

    def post(self,request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        user_data = serializer.data
        return Response(user_data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: did you defined `serializer_class` in `RegisterView` ?

Comment: i didnt understand what u mean

Comment: You didn't actually define the class to serialize the data. Check my answer for what is required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `serializer_class` for your view.

The docs for this particular view are [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#api-reference)

It looks like you've got one, but not assigned it in the class. So you want to do something like;

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import RegisterSerializer


class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        user_data = serializer.data
        return Response(user_data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

If your usecase is more complex, you can define a method to get the class also;

```py
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return FullAccountSerializer
        return BasicAccountSerializer
    
    def post(self, request):
        pass
```